# How to make svn save credentials when --non-interactive

Tags: shell-script, subversion

I'm trying to get `svn` to save my https username+password to ~/.subversion from within an automated script. I can pass creds on the command-line but I do not want to be prompted about whether to save the password unencrypted. Unfortunately this does not create ~/.subversion/:

```
svn --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username myusername --password secret co https://private.example.com/src/repo/
```

FYI I'm trying to do this for a Dockerfile that invokes a `bower install` with a `bower.json` that references a password-protected svn repo. Unfortunately there's no way to pass the svn credentials to `bower` via command-line or environment.

I am currently working around it by running svn interactively and letting it create ~/.subversion, then zipping up that entire directory and `ADD`ing it in the Dockerfile. I guess I could look at the file formats in ~/.subversion and create it with a script, but would rather let svn do it.

Answer (score 6):

Credentials will be saved if you use `--username` and `--password` without `--non-interactive` and  `--trust-server-cert`.

I'm assuming that you are using `--non-interactive` and `--trust-server-cert` to avoid the prompt that asks you to accept the certificate. To still avoid this prompt without those parameters, you can have your script create a copy of the file that is generated for each accepted cert in `~/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server`. This file will be the same for everyone for each respective server. I'm currently using this solution for a script.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently `--non-interactive` saves username but not password. I've already enabled password storage in `~/.subversion/servers`:

```
store-passwords = yes
store-plaintext-passwords = yes
store-auth-creds = yes
```

Looking at `svn help`, there is no command nor option that would appear relevant. I think it is impossible. You should ask SVN developers to be sure and file a bug report.

The file format under `auth` is not something you would want to script yourself. Most importantly, file name of the auth record seems to be a hash. That's not script-friendly. We need either special file format for hard-coded password list or a way to control this from command line.

Here's what I see under `~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/`:

File name `935...dc9e` (32 chars).

Content:

```
K 8
passtype
V 6
simple
K 8
password
V 8
p@$$w0rd
K 15
svn:realmstring
V 48
<https://svn.someplace.com:443> VisualSVN Server
K 8
username
V 5
johny
```

Comment: Looks to be some sort of netstring where V is the string length. Rather than simple mine was wincript. I edited mine to be simple but it knows. Probably via the filename

Comment: C:\Users\[you]\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple\

Comment: It is obviously a key-value map. K is for keys, V is for values. The number behind it is the length of the string. The real problem is the file name.

Answer (score 4):

I came up against this in an isolated environment (in which security was a non-issue) and resolved with simply running `svn ls` on the repository with the proper credentials with the help the (linux) `yes` command, though I found I had to remove the `~/.subversion` directory to get it work. Specifically:

`rm -fr ~/.subversion
yes yes | svn --username=user --password=guest ls svn://server/repo &>/dev/null`

Then all following svn commands will use these credentials on this server. Of course, one could pipe `yes yes` to any svn command that has the `--password` option.

enjoy!

Comment: This didn't work for me (all the auth values would be saved except the password) until I added the option: `--config-option='servers:global:store-plaintext-passwords=yes'`

Comment: This (since ~ 1.12??) needs to have been compiled in, else you need the other credential management options (like gpg-agent)